# How to create section title with tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, titlesec

I would like to create section title shown below.
[image]
I made an attempt with codes below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Number Theory}
\setcounter{section}{1} 
\tcbsidebyside[title= \section{Prime and Composite Numbers}, 
  sidebyside adapt=left, 
  colback=white, 
  colframe=blue!50!black, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  lower separated=false, 
  %drop lifted shadow,
  sidebyside align=top seam, 
  ]{%
  \Huge\textcolor{blue!50!black}{OBJECTIVES} 
  }{%
  \raggedright
  \begin{enumerate} 
     \item Identify whole numbers greater than one as prime or composite. 
     \item Factor a whole number into a product of prime numbers. 
     \item Find the greatest common factor of two or more whole numbers. 
     \item Find the least common multiple of two or more whole numbers. 
  \end{enumerate} 
  } 
\end{document}
```

The result is shown below.
[image]

Thanks in advance.